# How can I compute my final grade?

Tags: statistics

In one of my courses in the university, I got:

```
Final: (93 out of 100) [25% of the course]
2nd Major: (100 out of 100 + bouns 1) [12.5% of the course]
1st Major: (93 out of 100) [12.5% of the course]
Lab [30% of the course]:
    lab reports [11.25%]:
        lab#1: (100 out of 100)
        lab#2: (92 out of 100)
        lab#3: (86 out of 100)
        lab#4: (95 out of 100)
        lab#5: (80 out of 100)
        lab#6: (97 out of 100)
     projects [11.25%]:
        project#1: (100 out of 100)
        project#2: (100 out of 100)
        project#3: (100 out of 100)
     Two lab test [7.5%]:
        Lab Test#1: (82 out of 100)
        Lab Test#2: (100 out of 100)
Quizzes + Homework + Attendance [20% of the course]:
     Quizzes [13%]:
        Quiz#1: (100 out of 100)
        Quiz#2: (85 out of 100)
        Quiz#3: (85 out of 100)
        Quiz#4: (80 out of 100)
        Quiz#5: (100 out of 100)
        Quiz#6: (95 out of 100)
        Quiz#7: (100 out of 100)
        Quiz#8: (80 out of 100)
        Quiz#9: (100 out of 100)
     Homework [3%]:
        HW#1: (100 out of 100)
        HW#2: (100 out of 100)
        HW#3: (95 out of 100)
        HW#4: (0 out of 100)
        HW#5: (100 out of 100)
        HW#6: (100 out of 100)
        HW#7: (80 out of 100)
        HW#8: (100 out of 100)
        HW#9: (100 out of 100)
     Attendance (3.93 out of 4) [4%]
```

Could you please tell me how can I compute the final grade for the entire course? (I hope I get A+)

p.s: btw, is this a wrong place to ask such question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each separate component of the course, take its weighting and your percentage score for that course, and multiply them together. That is the contribution to your final grade from that component. For example, for attendance its weighting is 4% and you scored 3.93/4 = 98.25%. When you multiply, you get

4% x 98.25% = 3.93%

so the attendance component contributes 3.93% to your overall grade. For a more complicated example, on your lab tests you scored 182/200 = 91%, and they count for 7.5%, so you multiply and get

7.5% x 91% = 6.825%

so they contribute 6.825% to your final score. Do this for all the components and add them together to get your final score.

Answer (score 2):

Quick calculation - I get 94.2. Well done. C- for arithmetic, though. I have not included any bonuses (they can be calculated in any number of ways). You have an answer, now work it out as to how I got there. (*Hint:* Average each section into an overall percentage for each section, then reduce these averages by weighting for the section).

Comment: just seen chris' answer - he has the method.